# NSScrollView in NSSplitView autoresizming mask

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

i create a scrollview in a split view's top view in Interaface Build, i want to keep my document view always on the top of the top view, when i collapse the split view, the document view always on the bottom of the top view. any suggesstions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the constraint to handle this, or just in the -[viewWillAppear:], your parent view reposition the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

i have go the answer.
    - (BOOL) isFlipped
    {
        return YES;
    }